# Unhandled exceptions thrown by a method does not prevent compilation

Tags: java, methods, exception

So I have these two methods in a class:

```
public String getConsumerKey() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String consumerKey;
    consumerKey = getPropertyValueOrNull(getConfigPath(CONSUMERVALUESCONFIGNAME),"consumer_key");
    return consumerKey;     
}

private String getPropertyValueOrNull(String path, String key) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{   
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String value = null;

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(path));
    value = prop.getProperty(key);

    if ( value == null || value.isEmpty())
    {
        value = null;
    }
    return value;
}
```

And I call `getCosumerKey()` from the main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        try {
            MyClass.getInstance().getConsumerKey();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

When I run this code, there is no problem except that I am getting a FileNotFoundExcpetion. When I tried to add a catch block to handle the FileNotFoundException, I got an error saying that the exception is already handled from the IOException catch block.

Isn't the compiler supposed to prevent me from running the code and why does not compiler let me handle the exception?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`. If you want to handle it separately, you have to catch it first.

Comment: You could change `public String getConsumerKey() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException` to `public String getConsumerKey() throws IOException` as `FileNotFoundException` extends from `IOException`. There is a difference between runtime and compile time errors. The fact that you're get a `FileNotFoundException` simply means that what ever `getConfigPath(CONSUMERVALUESCONFIGNAME)` points does not exist, you existing code would catch this when it catches the `IOException`. If you want to handle the FNF exception, you would need a catch block BEFORE the `IOException` block

Comment: Oh I get it, you are right. So do you think it would be a good practice to remove the `throws FileNotFoundException` from the method and keep only the `IOException` or just handle them both in the right order?